# Query taking too long to execute and a unbelievable cost

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, psql

I am currently writing a query and I ran explain to check the query cost and time taken to run it. I observed that the cost is too high after I ran explain. Please find the below query.

```
create table l1.dm_sc_temp_pl_activity_p as 
select rel,licamt,tcamt, spsc, pdn, pmn4, pcs, clsldt, pci, cpdt, orgtin, bt, pcpldt, slc, sps, pm3, "ln", idt, ddt, rps, df, dat, pz, rpn, pih, pipid, pcpn, psa2, ingdt, incid, uqt, 
acoid||orgid  as orgid, pn, fn, pc, pm5, pm4, rpnpi, pfdt, sfn, catp, pdcs, pm1, st, pl, cltc, cpat, incn, gn, adjsn, clsfdt, acoid, sstp, orgn, sln, sid, drg, rcdt, tel3, pm2, rpsc, pmn3,
acoid||orgid||orgrid as orgrid, alat, inpn, tel2, drgn, pcpidt, acon, pcpid, id, pcpslid, pd, dob, psa1, orgrn, pcpslidt, pcy, pcpsln, pmn2, pmn5, cid, inpid, adjs, pmn1, eldt, empi, pcpfdt, cltp, tel1, pldt, pstn, spn, spnpi, mn, clid, 
efdt, capdt,ssa1,ssa2,sci,sstn,scy,sz,ftsa1,ftstn,ftz,ftci,ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5,
ad6,ad7,ad8,ad9,ad10,ad11,ad12,ad13,ad14,ad15,ad16,ad17,ad18,ad19,ad20,ad21,ad22,ad23,ad24,ad25,ad26,ad27,ad28,ad29,
adn1,adn2,adn3,adn4,adn5,adn6,adn7,adn8,adn9,adn10,adn11,adn12,adn13,adn14,
adn15,adn16,adn17,adn18,adn19,adn20,adn21,adn22,adn23,adn24,adn25,adn26,adn27,adn28,adn29 
from (
select  
 c.prov_addr1 as ftsa1,
c.prov_state as ftstn,
c.prov_zip as ftz,
c.prov_city as ftci,
c.iscap as rel,
cast(c.claimsvc_billedamt as decimal(18,2)) as licamt,
cast(c.claim_billedamt as decimal(18,2))  as tcamt,
trim(m.id) as id ,trim(m.tel1) as tel1,trim(m.tel2) as tel2,trim(m.tel3)as tel3,
'' as empi,trim(m.gn) as gn,psa1,psa2,pci,pcpldt,pl,trim(mn) as mn,trim(pz) as pz,trim(ln) as ln,
cast(m.dob as date) as dob,'N' as df,m.pcy,trim(m.fn) as fn,m.pcpfdt,m.pstn,
ssa1,ssa2,sci,sstn,scy,trim(sz) as sz,
--dm_prov
case when (trim(p.npi) in ('NULL','NA','')) then '' else trim(p.npi) end as pcpid,
case when (trim(p.npi) in ('NULL','NA','')) then '' else 'NPI' end as pcpidt,
p.lastname||','||p.firstname||' '||p.middlename as pcpn,
-- dm_vend
case when (trim(v.taxid) in ('NULL','NA','')) then '' else trim(v.taxid) end as pcpslid,
v.vendname as pcpsln,
case when (trim(v.taxid) in ('NULL','NA','')) then '' else 'NPI'  end as pcpslidt,
-- level
case when l."HPName"='Aetna Health of California' then '13'
when l."HPName"='Health Net' then '14'
when l."HPName"='Blue Shield of California' then '12'
when l."HPName"='United Healthcare of California' then '15'
when l."HPName"='Cigna for Health Care Professionals' then '16'
when l."HPName"='Anthem Blue Cross' then '17' end as incid,
l."HPName" as incn,
Case
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC United Healthcare Commercial' then '30'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Blue Shield 65 Plus' then '29'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC United Healthcare Canopy Commercial' then '31'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC United Healthcare Medicare Solutions' then '32'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Blue Shield Commercial' then '28'
when l."Progdescr"  in ('DHMNSC Health Net SmartCare Commercial','DHMNSC Health Net Canopy UC Blue and Gold Commercial',
'DHMNSC Health Net Canopy Care Commercial') then '33'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Aetna Commercial' then '34'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Cigna Commercial' then '35'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Health Net Commercial' then '36'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Anthem Blue Cross Commercial' then '37'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC Health Net Seniority Plus' then '38'
when l."Progdescr"='DHMNSC United Healthcare Canopy Medicare Advantage' then '50' end as inpid,
case when l."Progdescr"  in ('DHMNSC Health Net SmartCare Commercial','DHMNSC Health Net Canopy UC Blue and Gold Commercial',
'DHMNSC Health Net Canopy Care Commercial') then 'DHMNSC Health Net SmartCare Commercial'
else l."Progdescr"  end as inpn,
'3' as acoid,
'DHMN-SC' as acon,
case when l."LOB" ='M' then '6'
    when l."LOB" ='C' then '7' else '8' end as orgid,
case when l."LOB"='C' then 'Commercial'when l."LOB"='M' then 'Medicare' else "LOB" end as orgn,
case when  l."HPCode" not in ('PGM000295','PGM000294','PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326') then '7'  
     when l."HPCode" in ('PGM000295','PGM000294','PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326') then '9' else '8' end as orgrid,
case when  l."HPCode" not in ('PGM000295','PGM000294','PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326') then 'Non Canopy'  
     when l."HPCode" in ('PGM000295','PGM000294','PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326') then 'Canopy' else 'Other MedGroup' end as orgrn,
-- hardcode columns
'3a1bcd23-d88c-4c70-8ffa-267673232647' as pipid,
'Claims' as st,
l."HPName" as sstp,
'DataMart.bak' as sfn,
current_date as rcdt,
current_date as ingdt,
'claimline' as cltp,
'5' as sid,
'Patient ID' as idt,
 -- dm_claim
trim(c.claimno) as cid,
trim(c.seq) as clid,
'Professional' as cltc,
case when (trim(c.billtype) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.billtype) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.billtype) end as bt,
case when (trim(c.claim_fromdate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claim_fromdate as date) end as efdt,
case when (trim(c.claim_todate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claim_todate as date) end as eldt,
case when (trim(c.claim_recddate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claim_recddate as date) end as cpdt,
case when (trim(c.claim_paiddate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claim_paiddate as date) end as capdt,
case when (c.claim_netamt::decimal(18,2)='0' and c.iscap='1') then cast(c.claim_contramt as decimal(18,2)) 
else cast(c.claim_netamt as decimal(18,2))  end as pih,
case when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A1' then 'A'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A2' then 'A'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A3' then 'A'
    when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A4' then 'A'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R1' then 'C' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R2' then 'C' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R3' then 'C' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R4' then 'C' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R5' then 'C' else 'O' end as adjs,
case when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A1' then 'Adjusted'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A2' then 'Adjusted'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A3' then 'Adjusted'
    when trim(c.claimno)  like '%A4' then 'Adjusted'
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R1' then 'Cancelled' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R2' then 'Cancelled' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R3' then 'Cancelled' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R4' then 'Cancelled' 
     when trim(c.claimno)  like '%R5' then 'Cancelled' else 'Original' end as adjsn,
case when (trim(c.taxid) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.taxid) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.taxid) end as orgtin, 
case when (trim(c.npi ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.npi) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.npi) end as spnpi,
case when (c.prov_name in ('','NULL','NA') or c.prov_name is null) then p1.name else c.prov_name end as spn,
p1.ptxcd as spsc,
p1.psn as sps,
case when (trim(c.drgcode ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.drgcode) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.drgcode) end as drg,
c.drg_descr as drgn,
case when (trim(c.claimsvc_fromdate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claimsvc_fromdate as date) end as clsfdt,
case when (trim(c.claimsvc_todate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claimsvc_todate as date) end  as clsldt,
case when (trim(c.claimsvc_qty ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.claimsvc_qty) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.claimsvc_qty) end as uqt,
--cast(c.claimsvc_netamt as decimal(18,2)) as catp,
case when c.iscap='1' then cast(c.claimsvc_contramt as decimal(18,2)) else cast(c.claimsvc_netamt as decimal(18,2)) end as catp,
cast(c.claimsvc_allowedamt as decimal(18,2)) as alat,
cast(c.claimsvc_copayamt as decimal(18,2)) as cpat,
cast(c.claimsvc_deductamt as decimal(18,2)) as dat,
case when (trim(c.svccode ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.svccode) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.svccode) end as pc,
case when (trim(c.svc_longdescr ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.svc_longdescr) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.svc_longdescr) end as pn,
    ont.csys as pcs,
case when (trim(c.claimsvc_fromdate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claimsvc_fromdate as date) end as pfdt,                      
case when (trim(c.claimsvc_todate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claimsvc_todate as date) end  as pldt,                       
mf.pm1 ,
mf.pm2 ,
mf.pm3,
mf.pm4,
mf.pm5 ,
mf.pmn1,
mf.pmn2 ,
mf.pmn3,
mf.pmn4,
mf.pmn5,
case when c.poscode in('01','1') then 'Pharmacy'
when c.poscode in ('02','2') then 'Telehealth'
when c.poscode in('03','3') then 'School'
when c.poscode in ('04','4') then 'Homeless Shelter'
when c.poscode in ('05','5') then 'Indian Health Service Free-standing Facility'
when c.poscode='06' then 'Indian Health Service Provider-based Facility'
when c.poscode in ('07','7') then 'Tribal 638 Free-standing Facility'
when c.poscode in ('08','8') then 'Tribal 638 Provider-based Facility'
when c.poscode in('09','9') then 'Prison/Correctional Facility'
when c.poscode in ('10','77') then 'Unassigned'
when c.poscode='11' then 'Office'
when c.poscode='12' then 'Home'
when c.poscode='13' then 'Assisted Living Facility'
when c.poscode='14' then 'Group Home'
when c.poscode='15' then 'Mobile Unit'
when c.poscode='16' then 'Temporary Lodging'
when c.poscode='17' then 'Walk-in Retail Health Clinic'
when c.poscode='18' then 'Place of Employment-Worksite'
when c.poscode='19' then 'Off Campus-Outpatient Hospital'
when c.poscode='20' then 'Urgent Care facility'
when c.poscode='21' then 'Inpatient Hospital'
when c.poscode='22' then 'On Campus-Outpatient Hospital'
when c.poscode='23' then 'Emergency Room – Hospital'
when c.poscode in ('24','B') then 'Ambulatory Surgical Center'
when c.poscode='25' then 'Birthing Center'
when c.poscode='26' then 'Military Treatment Facility'
when c.poscode='31' then 'Skilled Nursing Facility'
when c.poscode='32' then 'Nursing Facility'
when c.poscode='33' then 'Custodial Care Facility'
when c.poscode='34' then 'Hospice'
when c.poscode='41' then 'Ambulance - Land'
when c.poscode='42' then 'Ambulance – Air or Water'
when c.poscode='49' then 'Independent Clinic'
when c.poscode='50' then 'Federally Qualified Health Center'
when c.poscode='51' then 'Inpatient Psychiatric Facility'
when c.poscode='52' then 'Psychiatric Facility-Partial Hospitalization'
when c.poscode='53' then 'Community Mental Health Center'
when c.poscode='54' then 'Intermediate Care Facility/ Individuals with Intellectual Disabilities'
when c.poscode='55' then 'Residential Substance Abuse Treatment Facility'
when c.poscode='56' then 'Psychiatric Residential Treatment Center'
when c.poscode='57' then 'Non-residential Substance Abuse Treatment Facility'
when c.poscode='60' then 'Mass Immunization Center'
when c.poscode='61' then 'Comprehensive Inpatient Rehabilitation Facility'
when c.poscode='62' then 'Comprehensive Outpatient Rehabilitation Facility'
when c.poscode='65' then 'End-Stage Renal Disease Treatment Facility'
when c.poscode='71' then 'Public Health Clinic'
when c.poscode='72' then 'Rural Health Clinic'
when c.poscode in ('81','A') then 'Independent Laboratory'
when c.poscode in ('99','?','O') then 'Other Place of Service' end as sln,
case when c.poscode in ('O','?') then '99'
when c.poscode='A' then '81'
when c.poscode='B' then '24'
when c.poscode in('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9') then '0'||c.poscode else c.poscode end slc,
case when (trim(c.pd ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.pd ) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.pd) end as pd,
case when (trim(c.pdn ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.pdn) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.pdn) end as pdn,
pdcs as pdcs,   
case when (trim(c.pd ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.pd ) is null)
    then Null else (
    case when (trim(c.claimsvc_fromdate) in ('','NULL','NA'))then null 
    else cast(c.claimsvc_fromdate as date) end )end as ddt,
case when (trim(c.ref_npi ) in ('','NULL','NA') or trim(c.ref_npi) is null)
    then '' else trim(c.ref_npi) end as rpnpi,
    p2."name" as rpn,
p2.ptxcd as rpsc,
p2.psn as rps,
ad1,ad2,ad3,ad4,ad5,
ad6,ad7,ad8,ad9,ad10,ad11,ad12,ad13,ad14,ad15,ad16,ad17,ad18,ad19,ad20,ad21,ad22,ad23,ad24,ad25,ad26,ad27,ad28,ad29,
adn1,adn2,adn3,adn4,adn5,adn6,adn7,adn8,adn9,adn10,adn11,adn12,adn13,adn14,
adn15,adn16,adn17,adn18,adn19,adn20,adn21,adn22,adn23,adn24,adn25,adn26,adn27,adn28,adn29
from (select * from l1.dm_proc_memb 
where hpcode in ('PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326','PGM000268', 'PGM000269', 'PGM000270', 'PGM000272', 'PGM000273', 'PGM000274', 'PGM000275', 'PGM000276', 'PGM000294', 'PGM000295')) m 
inner join l1.dm_proc_claim_p c 
on m.memb_id=c.claim_memb
left join l1.dm_proc_modif mf 
on mf.claimsvc_id=c.claimsvc_id 
left join l1."dm_prov" p on p.prov_id =m.prov_id
left join l1."dm_vend" v on v.vend_id =m.vend_id
left join (select * from l1."level" where "HPCode" in ('PGM000333','PGM000332','PGM000326','PGM000268', 'PGM000269', 'PGM000270', 'PGM000272', 'PGM000273', 'PGM000274', 'PGM000275', 'PGM000276', 'PGM000294', 'PGM000295')) l
on trim(l."HPCode" )=trim(m.hpcode)
left join l2.pd_npi p1 on trim(c.npi)=trim(p1.npi)
left join (select * from l2.pd_ontology where dtp ='procedure' )ont
on trim(ont.cval) =trim(c.svccode )
--left join l2.pd_ontology ontd
--on trim(ontd.cval) =trim(c.pd) and ontd.dtp ='diagnosis'
left join l2.pd_npi p2 on trim(c.ref_npi )=trim(p2.npi)
)f
```

I ran explain command onto this query and I observed the following op:

```
  Merge Cond: ((btrim((p2.npi)::text)) = (btrim((c.ref_npi)::text)))
  ->  Sort  (cost=1761851.74..1785989.13 rows=9654958 width=108)
        Sort Key: (btrim((p2.npi)::text))
        ->  Seq Scan on pd_npi p2  (cost=0.00..641739.58 rows=9654958 width=108)
  ->  Materialize  (cost=159139479153552696279040.00..159226719441637676679168.00 rows=17448057616994486190080 width=3383)
        ->  Sort  (cost=159139479153552696279040.00..159183099297595186479104.00 rows=17448057616994486190080 width=3383)
              Sort Key: (btrim((c.ref_npi)::text))
              ->  Merge Join  (cost=456947875487.57..261731712177051860992.00 rows=17448057616994486190080 width=3383)
                    Merge Cond: ((c.claim_memb)::text = (dm_proc_memb.memb_id)::text)
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=157761.50..10839427546273626.00 rows=2707460197662070 width=2450)
                          Join Filter: (btrim((c.npi)::text) = btrim((p1.npi)::text))
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=157761.50..9586754880584.63 rows=56084349568 width=2353)
                                Join Filter: (btrim((pd_ontology.cval)::text) = btrim((c.svccode)::text))
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.56..9362416722695.26 rows=43719408 width=2348)
                                      Join Filter: ((mf.claimsvc_id)::text = (c.claimsvc_id)::text)
                                      ->  Index Scan Backward using l1_dm_proc_claims_p_id_idx on dm_proc_claim_p c  (cost=0.56..17080655.54 rows=43719408 width=2036)
                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..376215.44 rows=14276496 width=352)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on dm_proc_modif mf  (cost=0.00..304832.96 rows=14276496 width=352)
                                ->  Materialize  (cost=157760.93..760260.39 rows=256565 width=14)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on pd_ontology  (cost=157760.93..758977.56 rows=256565 width=14)
                                            Recheck Cond: ((dtp)::text = 'procedure'::text)
                                            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pd_ont_idx_dtp  (cost=0.00..157696.79 rows=256565 width=0)
                                                  Index Cond: ((dtp)::text = 'procedure'::text)
                          ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..690014.37 rows=9654958 width=108)
                                ->  Seq Scan on pd_npi p1  (cost=0.00..641739.58 rows=9654958 width=108)
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=456947717726.07..459097227591.84 rows=429901973154 width=972)
                          ->  Sort  (cost=456947717726.07..458022472658.96 rows=429901973154 width=972)
                                Sort Key: dm_proc_memb.memb_id NULLS FIRST
                                ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=82668031.11..6531565545.79 rows=429901973154 width=972)
                                      Merge Cond: ((v.vend_id)::text = (dm_proc_memb.vend_id)::text)
                                      ->  Sort  (cost=88160.95..89633.33 rows=588951 width=96)
                                            Sort Key: v.vend_id
                                            ->  Seq Scan on dm_vend v  (cost=0.00..31716.51 rows=588951 width=96)
                                      ->  Materialize  (cost=82579870.16..83309815.39 rows=145989046 width=940)
                                            ->  Sort  (cost=82579870.16..82944842.77 rows=145989046 width=940)
                                                  Sort Key: dm_proc_memb.vend_id
                                                  ->  Merge Right Join  (cost=165139.84..2405511.13 rows=145989046 width=940)
                                                        Merge Cond: ((p.prov_id)::text = (dm_proc_memb.prov_id)::text)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using dm_prov_prov_id on dm_prov p  (cost=0.42..49937.79 rows=239291 width=160)
                                                        ->  Sort  (cost=165139.42..165444.47 rows=122018 width=844)
                                                              Sort Key: dm_proc_memb.prov_id
                                                              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=485.00..154830.89 rows=122018 width=844)
                                                                    Hash Cond: (btrim((dm_proc_memb.hpcode)::text) = btrim((level."HPCode")::text))
                                                                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on dm_proc_memb  (cost=481.71..153985.68 rows=122018 width=812)
                                                                          Recheck Cond: ((hpcode)::text = ANY ('{PGM000333,PGM000332,PGM000326,PGM000268,PGM000269,PGM000270,PGM000272,PGM000273,PGM000274,PGM000275,PGM000276,PGM000294,PGM000295}'::text[]))
                                                                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on l1_proc_memb_id_idx  (cost=0.00..451.20 rows=122018 width=0)
                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=3.13..3.13 rows=13 width=64)
                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on level  (cost=0.00..3.13 rows=13 width=64)
                                                                                Filter: (("HPCode")::text = ANY ('{PGM000333,PGM000332,PGM000326,PGM000268,PGM000269,PGM000270,PGM000272,PGM000273,PGM000274,PGM000275,PGM000276,PGM000294,PGM000295}'::text[]))
```

The cost taken by the query is too much. How can I reduce the cost and save time.
P.S I analyzed and found that left joins are increasing the cost. Please tell me how to manage this.

The max size of the tables is 32 GB.

Thanks!!

Comment: The cost value is the least interesting thing in an execution plan. Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (anaylze, buffers)` (only the SELECT part is enough)

Comment: explain analyze running for more than 12 hours now

Comment: Can you edit your post.  BEFORE the actual query, please edit and try to describe in simple English what the PURPOSE of this query is and what you are trying to accomplish.  Give some context can help now and in the future for others.  Also, I would strongly suggest editing your post and apply alias.column in your query so people know which columns are coming from what tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a big query, possibly too big for StackOverflow volunteers to wrap our heads around. I do notice one thing, though: you have multiple occurrences of

```
left join t on trim(t.col) = trim(a.col)   /* slow! */
```

That's a query-performance antipattern. If you want good performance you should go to great lengths to avoid calling functions on column values in WHERE and ON clauses. You want all columns in those clauses to be [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable). You can call functions on constant values, though.

Your objective should be to have that LEFT JOIN read:

```
left join t on t.col = a.col
```

And you should be sure the two sides of ON clauses have precisely the same data type; that makes it easier for the database server to do the joins efficiently.

Your monster query seems to have a presentation layer with a long SELECT clause with many complex column definitions. Then, in its last 15 lines or so, it has a data-retrieval subquery starting with `(select....`. If you're trying to optimize the query, you'll be wise to focus on the data-retrieval subquery, stripping away the presentation layer.

Once you make your ON and WHERE clauses sargable, you can move on to looking at your tables' indexes.

Comment: One way to make that join sargable is to create indexes on those expressions.

Comment: Thank You for taking time and answering the above question. I will take into account the two to three points mentioned in both the comments and check the cost/exec time.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what O.Jones indicated, all those instances where you DO have TRIM() calls, you should be STORING your data pre-trimmed to prevent calling trim all over the place.

An additional item to make things easier is to have some lookup tables if they are not already present.  You have all those CASE/WHEN context checks, such as for HPName, Progdesc and HPCode values.  You should be able to have those in a lookup table and JOIN to those to get the given ID.  And more typical than not, it would better to have one lookup table of the ID and the Name/Description once so you are not repeating all records with the literal value 'Aetna Health of California' or 'Blue Shield of California'.  Your child-level table should have the providers ID of 12, 13, 14, etc vs the long name.  That is where things SHOULD be going.

Good luck moving forward.

Comment: Thank You @DRapp for taking time to go through my post and answering my question. I will give this a try.

Comment: @PratyushSrivastava, if it works, most credit should go to O.Jones answer, so check that if it does work / resolve your issue.

Comment: You are correct. Most of the cost reduced due to trim. However, your answer also helped me reduce the cost too even though it was small.